# Qt, no such slot

Tags: c++, qt

why do I get this

```
Object::connect: No such slot Ide::on_action_Exit_triggered(index)
Object::connect:  (sender name:   'actionClose_Project')
Object::connect:  (receiver name: 'Ide')
```

when I try this:

```
connect(this->ui->actionClose_Project, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(on_action_Exit_triggered(index)));

void Ide::on_action_Exit_triggered(int index)
{
  qDebug()<<"test\n";
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Use the type of parameter, not its name.

Comment: an where from do I get the value?

Comment: The correct signature is `SLOT(on_action_Exit_triggered(int))`, not `SLOT(on_action_Exit_triggered(index))`.

Comment: And as @Mat points out, this will not work, because `triggered()` has fewer parameters than `on_action_Exit_triggered(int)`.

Answer (score 4):

Please insert prototype of function  like this :

```
connect(this->ui->actionClose_Project, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(on_action_Exit_triggered(int)));
```

This format you use isn't common to use slot. the signal and slot should be same in parameters.

Comment: While this is correct, I don't think it'll work. The signal must have at least as many params as the slot it's connected to.

Comment: @Mat : I think you can connect to a slot that has more parameters if those parameters have a default value in the slot declaration.

Comment: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/signalsandslots.html#signals-and-slots-with-default-arguments - no, it won't work as written above.